# Instalação de pacote do Composer

Tags: php, codeigniter, composer

Eu não consigo instalar um pacote do **composer** no meu computador windows do qual eu precisava pois uma biblioteca de documentação do Codeigniter depende desse pacote para rodar. Estou usando Windows 7 com Gitbash e o composer está funcionando perfeitamente. O pacote em questão é:

### apigen/apigen

https://packagist.org/packages/apigen/apigen

### e o comando executado em modo administrador é:

composer global require --dev apigen/apigen

### A tela de erro é essa:

[image: inserir a descrição da imagem aqui]

Peço ajuda para instalar a biblioteca no meu ambiente.

Comment: Uma biblioteca instalada no CodeIgniter! Qual é a biblioteca? de certo o problema está no versionamento dos pacotes? mas, qual a biblioteca principal?

Comment: @VirgilioNovic na verdade ela não é uma dependência, é uma classe de documentação para o Codeigniter e não quer instalar no global.

Comment: Certo Marcos qual é essa classe? isso que gostaria de saber

Comment: @VirgilioNovic o apigen é a classe. É a classe de documentação.

Comment: Então faz um teste instale `composer global require apigen/apigen "^4.1"` ou `composer require apigen/apigen "^4.1"` sem o global